# How to select a comment as an answer.

Tags: support, comment, accepted-answer

There is my [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1071261/how-the-cardinality-of-mathbbr-and-mathbbr-same/1071289?noredirect=1#comment2180566_1071289), here till now in both the answers there is not anything what I needed and so none of them is selected by me.

In comments under both the answers I'm getting something new and that is very close to what I was asking in my question. If the discussion goes 
on then I think that soon I will get to the answer.

Now suppose if somebody has given the answer in the comment then I can only mark it as `useful`. I who posted the question knows that, that comment is the answer but a new user or anybody who is thinking of a similar problem will not be able to find the answer because that user will be searching the answer in the answers not in the comments.

So is there any way by which I can mark a comment as an answer.

Comment: No. But you could leave a comment, suggesting that the commenter post her comment as an answer.

Comment: @GerryMyerson But many times it happen that all the comments are not visible initially, at that time user has to click on `show more comments` but many times we do not wish to see all the comments because we think that they are not having any useful information.

Comment: This is not bad on your part, it is on the commenter ( I have done this is in the past/ and not so distant past) to leave the comment section as resource for clarification rather than answering..